# Single sign-on between different versions

Tags: users, 8, authentication-authorization

I have two websites one in Drupal 7 and other in Drupal 8. I want to implement single sign-on between these two websites.

My users are registered in Drupal 7 and I want my users authenticated from there to use Drupal 8 website. What is the feasible solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that questions asking to recommend modules are off-topic for us, and that _feasible_ is rather subjective.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Sorry I didn't get you.